# check with procmail if a file exists and set a option

Tags: procmail

I want to check with procmail if a file exists and depending on this set DROPPRIVS=yes
if its not true stay with DROPPRIVS=no

Why is this not working?

```
:0 w
* `test -f $HOME/mail/.procmailrc` ?? 1
{
    DROPPRIVS=yes
}
```

Comment: Hmph, looks like you basically already solved this in http://serverfault.com/a/579348/98333

Comment: anyway your second solution was much more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the output from `test` is nothing at all, so the backticks will capture an empty string; presumably, you actually want to capture the exit code from `test`, not the output.

But anyway, backticks are not valid in a condition.  You could use backticks outside of a condition and compare the result, or the exit code, to a variable:

```
EXISTS=`test -f $HOME/mail/.procmailrc`
EXITCODE=$?
:0
* EXITCODE ?? ^^1^^
{ DROPPRIVS=yes }
```

but more idiomatically and elegantly, you can use a single question mark to examine the exit code of an external command:

```
:0w
* ! ? test -f $HOME/mail/.procmailrc
{ DROPPRIVS=yes }
```

The `!` negates the condition, so any non-zero exit code triggers the action.

Comment: the sond solution works. But I do not understand "? !"

Comment: `?` means examine exit code and `!` inverts the truth value. `test -f` is true when the file exists, but we want truth (successful condition) when it doesn't.